# What are the special roofs for winning in the Players Club?

Tags: tiny-tower-vegas

I was in top 30 for one of the top 10 clubs (though not the top club) and earned the Player's Club Silver roof. Then I was in the top 30 again for one of the top 10 clubs, but didn't get a new roof as far as I could tell. What determines which special roof you unlock? Is it where your club comes in? Where you come in, inside the club? Random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are probably a players club gold, silver and bronze roofs.

I have only gotten the silver and bronze ones though. I will not give you another roof if you end up at the same prize level again.

I am willing to bet if you are club number 1 you get the gold roof.

[image: Here Players Club Info Screen from the game.]

Comment: Did you get the silver when you were in #2-#10, and the bronze when you were in #11-100?

Comment: Yep that is correct silver for being like 8th and bronze for being like 26th I believe.